# how can I search inside listView using flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../app_data.dart';
import '../widgets/TopicItem.dart';

class TitleTopic extends StatefulWidget {

@override
State<TitleTopic> createState() => _TitleTopicState();
}
```

class _TitleTopicState extends State {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

```
   appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color(0Xfff5d4037),
     automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
     title: Text('Learn English', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffffffff) , fontSize: 18 , fontFamily: 'Tajawal' , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
   ),
 
    body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          )
        ),

      child: Column(
        
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.white24,
            child: TextField ( 
              onChanged: (value) => search(),
              onSubmitted: print, 
              decoration: InputDecoration(  
                border: InputBorder.none,  
                hintText: 'search here ..'  ,
              ), 
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontFamily: 'Tajawal'),
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, 
            ),
          ),

          Expanded(               
             child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  children:
                  Categories_data.map((categoryData) => TopicItems(id: categoryData.id, 
                   title:  categoryData.title,)
                ).toList(),
             )
        ],
      ),
    ),
);
```

}
}

TopicItems it just widgte to display (title:  categoryData.title ) inside card

I have data saved inside app_data.dart , I can bring it in my app using list as you show above

app_data.dart file contain :

const Categories_data =
const [
Category(
id: 'c1',
title: 'hello world',
),
Category(
id: 'c2',
title: 'say good morning',
),
Category(
id: 'c3',
title: 'say good bye ',
),
Category(
id: 'c4',
title: 'say hello',
),

I need a function search() when I type in textfield bring out the data from app_data.dart
to listview

Comment: You can't search in ListView. Filter your data map and regenerate the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing searching for data in a `List` with the `ListView` widget. You cannot search a `ListView`.
You can use the `showSearch` function to allow the user to search within your list of `Strings`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showSearch.html

It is not the easiest to implement, but you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is on text change, simply search for the item in your `Categories_data` and provide it as filteredList. Kindly check below example.

```
class TitleTopicState extends State {
  List _filteredCategoriesData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_filteredCategoriesData==null){
      _filteredCategoriesData = Categories_data;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0Xfff5d4037),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'Learn English',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xffffffff),
              fontSize: 18,
              fontFamily: 'Tajawal',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.white24,
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: _onQuery,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Search here ..',
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Tajawal'),
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                children: _filteredCategoriesData.map((categoryData) => TopicItems(
                      id: categoryData.id,
                      title: categoryData.title,
                    )).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQuery(String keyword) async {
    if (keyword.trim().isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    final filteredResults = Categories_data.where(
      (data) => (data.title.contains(keyowrd)),
    );
    setState(() => _filteredCategoriesData = filteredResults);
  }
}
```